# No protection if a powered stepper is turned manually?

Tags: stepper-motor

It is not clear to me what happens inside the stepper motor when it is manually and rapidly rotated in clockwise/counterclockwise, overcoming the torque of the motor.

As I understand, fly-back diodes are protecting the driver when the windings are not energized and the stepper is acting like a generator.
So it seems to me that no additional protection is necessary if I manually rotate the shaft of the motor when it is fully powered. But I'm not 100% sure on this...

### Details

I ordered [this](https://www.orientalmotor.de/Products/Stepper_motors/Stepper_motors/high_torque_2phase_motors_pkp/?arid=23564) little bipolar NEMA 11 stepper, driven from this [driver](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/12859).
The shaft of the stepper is linked to the axis of a knob with a 5-to-1 ratio spur gear. No half-stepping, no micro-stepping.

I plan to use an 8-diodes-array to protect the driver board:

[image: Texas Instruments UC3610]

Comment: The diodes in the A4988 driver chip should be sufficient

Comment: At higher speeds, you do have to watch what happens when you're pushing voltage back into the power supply. Especially if that voltage exceeds the supply rating. Consider whether you need to dump generated power into a load resistor or charge a battery with it.

Comment: @BrianDrummond it is difficult to evaluate the rpm-speed: if I turn manually rapidly the knob of 90° then the shaft of the motor will make 1,25 turns (because of the 1-to-5 spur gear). But... what is the speed of my hand???

Comment: True, but you can easily measure voltage (DC easiest, after the diodes)

Comment: @BrianDrummond: so it seems that I have to wait for the delivery of the stepper... Then I can do some measurements of current and voltage when I quickly turn the knob.
Anyway, I was expecting that if the windings are already energized then the stepper cannot turn itself into a generator. After your comment I started thinking that I'm deeply wrong...

Comment: If the motor is decelerating the load, it is acting as a generator! The kinetic energy has to go somewhere!

Comment: @whitegreg56: this would happens with any stepper (even the ones of my cnc-router machine) when the rpm are changed by the program while working. Nevertheless I never noticed any particular protection adopted in many project that I saw on Arduino/Sparkfun forums...

Comment: @whitegreg56: Anyway, the diodes should work in this circumstances. i.e. the energy should be (slowly) dissipated into extra-heat by the diodes because of the voltage drop. Or I'm wrong on this?

Comment: If the deceleration is small enough, there is no need for protection.  The diodes will dissipate some of the energy developed during deceleration.  But, mostly it is a matter of  pumping current backwards into the power supply.  If the deceleration is rapid enough, the current from the power supply will go negative and any capacitor on its output will be "pumped up" in voltage.

Comment: @whitegreg56: there is no way to use a big non-polarized cap (ceramic?) to temporarily absorb the current kicked back from the motor? In that way the cap should act as an "equalizer" between the current pumped in from the driver and the (eventual) current pumped back from the motor even if the windings are energized. This is just my first thought without going deeply into the matter...

Comment: You don't need a non-polarized capacitor.  An electrolytic (polarized) capacitor would be just fine.  In fact, there may already be one.  Look at the schematic for your power supply!

Comment: @whitegreg56: Power supply? Do mean the driver, yes? At the moment I'm using the Big Easy Driver from Sparkfun. I will take a look at the schematic.
P.S. I also looked at the stuff from Trinamic. Cool and professional stuff but I'm not at that level at the moment..

Comment: @gimpo: What is supplying the power to run the motor?  A battery?, a 24V power supply?, or something else?  If it is a battery, no need for a capacitor....the current kicked back from the motor (when decelerating) will charge the battery!

Comment: @whitegreg56: final product will be powered from a 12V motorcycle battery. I was worry that the current pumped back could damage the driver board with some kind of voltage spike. So it seems not the case.

Answer (score 2):

Well, through the comments, I think you answered your own question.  If the stepper motor is powered up, the diodes in the driver chip (A4988) should direct any kick back into your battery.  If you are using a DC power supply (from 120 VAC) then you need an electrolytic capacitor...this is shown as a 100 microfarad on the data sheet for the driver chip (between VBB1,VBB2 and ground).  The DC power supply may have a capacitor on its output as well.

Comment: Thanks for summarizing up the "answers" in the comments.
I plan to use the standard 12V-18Ah battery of my motorcycle.